# Заполнение Codemirror посредством vba

Tags: javascript, html, vba, codemirror

Всем доброго дня!

Прошу помочь разобраться в вопросе: как достучаться из VBA до CodeMirror.

Цель: передавать скрипт из поля таблицы в редактор кода, который реализован на форме Access в элементе управления WebBrowser с помощью CodeMirror.
Получается "схватить" textArea, с которой связан Codemirror, но насколько я понял, это не то, что нужно.

Буду крайне признателен за помощь.

Answer (score 0):

Решил через добавление на форму скрытого текстареа, в который дублируется текст из контрола, к которому прикручен CodeMirror.VBA читает текст из него.